# Function in MATLAB to draw samples from Uniform Distribution

Tags: matlab, random, montecarlo, probability-density, uniform-distribution

I want to draw randomly from a Uniform Distribution defined as below by code in MATLAB :-

`pd1 = makedist('Uniform','lower',-0.0319,'upper',0.0319); % X1`

In MATLAB the usual command is `random()` but the help file tells me its only for Guassian mixture distributions. So can it also be extended for use in Uniform Distribution or is there any other function to explicitly draw randomly for Monte Carlo Simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a uniform variable, you can use [`random`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html#responsive_offcanvas) as follows:

```
lower_limit = -0.0319;
upper_limit = 0.0319;
sz = [1 10];
x = random('unif', lower_limit, upper_limit, sz);
```

But this is **overly complicated**, and slow: `random` analyzes the inputs and calls [`unifrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/unifrnd.html), which in turn does some checks and finally calls [`rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html). Instead, you can just use:

```
lower_limit = -0.0319;
upper_limit = 0.0319;
sz = [1 10];
x = lower_limit + (upper_limit-lower_limit)*rand(sz);
```

In general, there are **three levels** of functions that can be used to create (pseudo)random numbers:

- `random` is a sort of common interface for generating random numbers. Based on the specified inputs it calls the appropriate function, such as `unifrnd` for a uniform distribution, `exprnd` for an exponential distribution, ...
- There are specific functions for each distribution, typically called "`···rnd`": `unifrnd`, `exprnd`, `normrnd`, ... Internally, these call some of the functions to be described next, and apply some transformation to achieve the desired distribution.
- The lowest-level (built-in), fastest functions are: `rand` for a continuous uniform distribution on (0,1), `randn` for a normal (Gaussian) distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, and `randi` for a uniform discrete distribution.

Comment: But in the scenario I don't have the upper and lower limits but I have ```pd1``` with the information that its a uniform distribution, what should I be doing then? Here ```pd1``` is only information I have from a previous data suppose

Comment: I get what you mean now. That kind of solves my problem. I can use either ```random()``` or ```unifrnd()``` , but interestingly only ```random()```  allows me to use a probability distribution.

Comment: If you only have `pd1` as input data you have to use `random`: something like `x = random(pd1.DistributionName, pd1.ParameterValues(1), pd1.ParameterValues(2), sz)`